# cannot read property 'street' of undefined in angular forms

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

i just trying angular 6 with spring boot.I just wanna using nested class .Here is my class.But i cant screen users. I got this error.Could you help me?

```
 export  class Address {

street: string;
    suite: string;
  city: string;
 zipcode: string;


}
    import {Address} from './address';


    export class User {

     id: number;
     name: string;
     email: string;
     address: Address;
     phone: string;
     website: string;

    }
```

this is my html code

```
 <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" >
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="id">User Id</label>
      <input type="text"   class="form-control"  id="id"   required [(ngModel)]="users.id" name="id">

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text"  class="form-control"  id="name"  required [(ngModel)]="users.name" name="name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="email"  class="form-control"  id="email" required [(ngModel)]="users.email"  name="email">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for ="street"  >Address street</label>
      <input  type="text"  class="form-control" id="street"  required [(ngModel)]="users.address.street"  name="street">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your class make sure you make the address an actual instance as well. By default address will be undefined. You can do it in the constructor, example below :

```
 export class User {

  constructor() {
    this.address = new Address()
  }

  id: number;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  address: Address;
  phone: string;
  website: string;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should have a `users` property defined on your Component Class to make this work:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class YourComponent  {
  users = {
    id: '',
    address: {}
  };
}
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-json-placeholder-form?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: I think he must have his model already otherwise the error would be 'cannot read property 'id' of undefined'. But yes more code of his controller would help

Comment: Lenny D you are right.This error has vahished. Maybe i got error in back end. Thank you for your valuable contributions :)

Comment: @LennyD, he's only getting this error for `street` as it is a field in `address`. Looks like `address` was not defined on it. And hence the error said can't read property `address` of `undefined`.

Comment: @cmyldz No worries, please mark my answer as correct.

Comment: @SiddAjmera yes thats what i'm saying, please see my answer. He already has the model! Your answer suggested he didn't have model at all, in which case he would have had an error on the first property which was the 'id'

Comment: @LennyD i push the flag unintentionally.Im so sorry